# Box2D collision detection?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am adding a b2BodyDef to my CCScene like so:

```
    b2BodyDef platformBodyDef;
    platformBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    platformBodyDef.position.Set(40, 495);
    platformBodyDef.userData = platforms;
    _body = _world->CreateBody(&platformBodyDef);
```

I know I am supposed to use contact listeners but I am new to Box2D and this is like another language to me so how would I code it to see if one of the CCSprites in my CCScene collides with this b2BodyDef? This b2BodyDef will be animating but I am not worrying about that right now.
Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good tutorial describing how to do this [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/505/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-22)

Basically what you do is create a contactListener which listens for collisions between bodies. Make sure your sprites are tagged, and then in the contact listener you load up the spriteData of the two objects that collided. By checking the tags you can identify the sprites that collided.

From there you can do pretty much anything, as you have a reference to the sprite, the body and the world. For example, as in the aforementioned example, removing the brick.

Comment: Since I made this thread, I successfully added it to my project. But the problem I am currently facing is how to stop multiple callbacks for one collision. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - hopefully it will help someone else... In the precalc method of the contactListener you can cancel events. So you coud tag the body with a tag to be removed in that method and then cancel the event. Then when you iterate through all the bodies and update their positions etc... if the sprite is tagged to be removed you remove it.

Comment: Thats what I do, I just change the tag as soon as it collides and then the collision if statement does not get called anymore for that collision!